# ¿Por qué no recibe los datos en el método?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

Tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar un query en c# y es que comando.ExecuteReader() no recibe la data 
esto es lo que tengo en c#:

```
   public List<FlotasBE> ConsultarFlota(string flota, string fechini, string fechfin, string min, string max)
            {
                //HabilitarCaracterEspecial();

                List<FlotasBE> resultado = new List<FlotasBE>();

                try
                {
                    OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(ConexionDA.ConcectaIntranet());

                    OracleCommand comando = new OracleCommand("Select * from( SELECT ROWNUM as NumFila,f.* FROM( " +
      " SELECT " +
       "    (select count(*) FROM comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA VD left join Clpr_Flota_Vehiculo@clubgazel fv on(Fv.de_placa = vd.placa and fv.st_flota_vehiculo = 'Y') " +
       "   inner join Clpd_Flota@clubgazel f on fv.Co_Flota = f.id " +
       "   inner join Clpb_Cliente_Empresa@clubgazel e on f.Co_Cliente_Empresa = e.id " +
      "  WHERE " +
       "  FECHA_PROCESO >= TO_DATE('" + fechini + "', 'DD/MM/RRRR') " +
       "   AND FECHA_PROCESO <= TO_DATE('" + fechfin + "', 'DD/MM/RRRR') ) total," +
        //((flota == "0") ? " " : "  AND f.De_flota_area like '" + flota + "'") + ") total, " +
        //"   ROWNUM as NumFila, " +
        "   Vd.Ruc, " +
       "    f.De_flota_area Flota, " +
        "   VD.PLACA, " +
        "   VD.COD_ESTACION Cod_EDS, " +
        "   (SELECT E.DESCRIPCION FROM comercial.ESTACION E WHERE E.COD_ESTACION = VD.COD_ESTACION) EDS, " +
        "   to_char(VD.FECHA_PROCESO, 'DD/MM/RRRR') Fecha_Proceso, " +
        "   TO_CHAR(FECHA_VENTA, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI') Fecha_Venta, " +
        "   VD.CANTIDAD M3, " +
        "   VD.PRECIO_UNITARIO PU, " +
         //"   --VD.VALOR_VENTA Valor Venta, " +
         //  "  --VD.IGV, " +
         "  VD.PRECIO_VENTA Precio_Venta, " +
         "  CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)), 4, 1) = '9' THEN CASE WHEN VD.RUC = '20511995028' THEN 'PROMOCION' ELSE 'CREDITO' END ELSE 'CONTADO' END TIPO_VENTA, " +
        "         TRUNC(PRECIO_VENTA - (CANTIDAD * PRECIO_UNITARIO), 2) INC_DESC, " +
       "    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)), 4, 1) = '1' THEN 'FACTURA' WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)),4,1)= '2' THEN 'BOLETA' ELSE 'NOTA DESPACHO' END TIPO_DOCUMENTO, " +
       "         (SERIE) || '-' || TO_CHAR(NUMERO, '0000000') DOCUMENTO, " +
       "    TO_CHAR(VD.FEC_INICIO_LECTURA, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI') HORA_INICIO, " +
       "    round((VD.FECHA_VENTA - VD.fec_inicio_lectura) * 60 * 24) MIN_DESP, " +
       "    CASE WHEN NVL(f.De_flota_area, ' ') = ' ' THEN 'Placa no Asociada en ClubGazel' ELSE ' ' END Observacion " +
      "  FROM comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA VD left join Clpr_Flota_Vehiculo @clubgazel fv on(Fv.de_placa= vd.placa and fv.st_flota_vehiculo= 'Y') " +
        "  inner join Clpd_Flota @clubgazel f on fv.Co_Flota = f.id and f.ST_FLOTA = 'Y'" +
       "   inner join Clpb_Cliente_Empresa @clubgazel e on f.Co_Cliente_Empresa = e.id " +
       " WHERE " +
        " FECHA_PROCESO >= TO_DATE('" + fechini + "', 'DD/MM/RRRR') " +
          "AND FECHA_PROCESO <= TO_DATE('" + fechfin + "', 'DD/MM/RRRR') " +
         //((flota == "0") ? " " : "  AND f.De_flota_area like '" + flota + "' ") +
    ") f " +
    ((flota == "0") ? " " : "  WHERE Flota =  '" + flota + "' ") +
    ") where NumFila BETWEEN " + min + " and " + max + " ", conexion);


                    comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    OracleDataReader reader;
                    conexion.Open();
                    reader = comando.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        FlotasBE res = new FlotasBE()
                        {
                            total = (reader["total"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["total"]).ToString(),
                            NumFila = (reader["NumFila"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["NumFila"]).ToString(),
                            Ruc = (reader["Ruc"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Ruc"]).ToString(),
                            Flota = (reader["Flota"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Flota"]).ToString(),
                            PLACA = (reader["PLACA"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["PLACA"]).ToString(),
                            Cod_EDS = (reader["Cod_EDS"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Cod_EDS"]).ToString(),
                            EDS = (reader["EDS"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["EDS"]).ToString(),
                            Fecha_Proceso = (reader["Fecha_Proceso"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Fecha_Proceso"]).ToString(),
                            Fecha_Venta = (reader["Fecha_Venta"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Fecha_Venta"]).ToString(),
                            M3 = (reader["M3"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["M3"]).ToString(),
                            PU = (reader["PU"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["PU"]).ToString(),
                            Precio_Venta = (reader["Precio_Venta"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Precio_Venta"]).ToString(),
                            TIPO_VENTA = (reader["TIPO_VENTA"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["TIPO_VENTA"]).ToString(),
                            INC_DESC = (reader["INC_DESC"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["INC_DESC"]).ToString(),
                            TIPO_DOCUMENTO = (reader["TIPO_DOCUMENTO"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["TIPO_DOCUMENTO"]).ToString(),
                            DOCUMENTO = (reader["DOCUMENTO"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["DOCUMENTO"]).ToString(),
                            HORA_INICIO = (reader["HORA_INICIO"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["HORA_INICIO"]).ToString(),
                            MIN_DESP = (reader["MIN_DESP"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["MIN_DESP"]).ToString(),
                            Observacion = (reader["Observacion"] == DBNull.Value) ? String.Empty : (reader["Observacion"]).ToString()
                        };

                        resultado.Add(res);
                    }
                    conexion.Close();
                    conexion.Dispose();
                    comando.Dispose();


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw e;
                }

                //InhabilitarCaracterEspecial();

                return resultado;
            }
```

Yo he probado esa consulta en oracle con los datos completos y se que devuelve información , pero esta no se recibe en c#.

```
Select * from(
SELECT ROWNUM as NumFila,f.* FROM (  
SELECT 
(select count(*) FROM comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA VD left join Clpr_Flota_Vehiculo@clubgazel fv on (Fv.de_placa=vd.placa and fv.st_flota_vehiculo='Y')    
inner join Clpd_Flota@clubgazel f on fv.Co_Flota=f.id    
inner join Clpb_Cliente_Empresa@clubgazel e on f.Co_Cliente_Empresa=e.id   
WHERE /*substr(vd.serie,4,1)='9'
AND*/ FECHA_PROCESO >= TO_DATE('01/04/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR')  
AND FECHA_PROCESO <= TO_DATE('20/04/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR') ) total,

--ROWNUM as NumFila,    
Vd.Ruc,     
f.De_flota_area Flota,    
VD.PLACA,    
VD.COD_ESTACION Cod_EDS,    
(SELECT E.DESCRIPCION FROM comercial.ESTACION E WHERE E.COD_ESTACION=VD.COD_ESTACION) EDS,    
to_char(VD.FECHA_PROCESO,'DD/MM/RRRR') Fecha_Proceso,    
TO_CHAR(FECHA_VENTA, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI') Fecha_Venta,    
VD.CANTIDAD M3,    
VD.PRECIO_UNITARIO PU,
--VD.VALOR_VENTA "Valor Venta",
--VD.IGV,
VD.PRECIO_VENTA Precio_Venta,   
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)),4,1)='9' THEN CASE WHEN VD.RUC='20511995028' THEN 'PROMOCION' ELSE 'CREDITO' END ELSE 'CONTADO' END TIPO_VENTA,          
TRUNC(PRECIO_VENTA-(CANTIDAD*PRECIO_UNITARIO),2) INC_DESC,     
CASE WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)),4,1)='1' THEN 'FACTURA' WHEN SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(SERIE)),4,1)='2' THEN 'BOLETA' ELSE 'NOTA DESPACHO' END TIPO_DOCUMENTO,          
(SERIE) || '-' || TO_CHAR(NUMERO,'0000000') DOCUMENTO,     
TO_CHAR(VD.FEC_INICIO_LECTURA, 'DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI') HORA_INICIO,     
round((VD.FECHA_VENTA-VD.fec_inicio_lectura)*60*24) MIN_DESP,     
CASE WHEN NVL(f.De_flota_area,' ')=' ' THEN 'Placa no Asociada en ClubGazel' ELSE ' ' END Observacion   
FROM comercial.VENTA_DETALLADA VD left join Clpr_Flota_Vehiculo@clubgazel fv on (Fv.de_placa=vd.placa and fv.st_flota_vehiculo='Y')   
inner join Clpd_Flota@clubgazel f on fv.Co_Flota=f.id and f.ST_FLOTA = 'Y'    
inner join Clpb_Cliente_Empresa@clubgazel e on f.Co_Cliente_Empresa=e.id 
WHERE /*substr(vd.serie,4,1)='9'
AND*/ FECHA_PROCESO >= TO_DATE('01/04/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR') 
AND FECHA_PROCESO <= TO_DATE('20/04/2018', 'DD/MM/RRRR')   

) f
WHERE Flota = 'SR.TA-SEÑOR TAXI'
)
where NumFila BETWEEN 1 and 30;
```

Si alguien tiene una idea ojala me puedan apoyar

Comment: ¿Porqué no usas una cadena verbatim? es mucho mas claro y menos propenso a errores.

Comment: Si usted tiene errores, reemplace `catch (Exception e) { throw e; }` y [edit] la pregunta con la descripción completa del error/excepción. En su pregunta no es claro si el código "en C#" o la consulta es el problema.

Comment: lo probé antes y no arrojaba ningún error, hice algunas consultas y al final es por un tema del lenguaje de la región configurado en el Oracle ya que como está en inglés no reconoce la "Ñ"